# How to redirect page using targetURL with my datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tweaking with Twisty's script - [Using Jquery UI Datepicker to redirect to URL: Change URL value based on the selected date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727382/using-jquery-ui-datepicker-to-redirect-to-url-change-url-value-based-on-the-sel)

I am trying let user click on a date which will be redirect to a page according to the date selected.

If user click on 18 January it should be redirected to datpicker.com/18-01-2022. If the date 22 March is selected it should go to datpicker.com/22-03-2022.

But I am getting this alert - Redirect to undefined, no matter how I tweaked the script.
Hence, I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Pick a date:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  function getDayOfYear(n) {
    var s = new Date(n.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
    var d = (n - s) + ((s.getTimezoneOffset() - n.getTimezoneOffset()) * 60 * 1000);
    var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var day = "00" + Math.floor(d / oneDay);
    return day.substr(-3);
  }

  var targetUrl;

  $("#datepicker")
    .datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      onSelect: function(dateText) {
      datePicked = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd-mm-yy', dateText);
       dayPicked = getDayOfYear(datePicked);
       targetUrl  =  "https://datpicker.com/" + dayPicked;
        $(this).change();
      }
    })
    .change(function() {
      alert("Redirect to " + targetUrl);
      //window.location.href = targetUrl;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open('https://www.abdo-host.com', '_blank');
```

or

```
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = 'https://www.abdo-host.com';
  link.target = '_blank';
  var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
      'view': window,
      'bubbles': false,
      'cancelable': true
  });
  link.dispatchEvent(event);
```